# How to print shared preferences values from new encrypted shared preferences in android?

Tags: android, encryption, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store some shared preferences in view-model with fragment .. then when i close the app and re-open it i want to print them in some activity but it can't be printed!

This is my code :

my fragment :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentSettingsBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater, R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);


        SettingsViewModel settingsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new SettingsViewModelFactory(this, new SettingsModel())).get(SettingsViewModel.class);
        binding.setSettings(settingsViewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        binding.languageSetting.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // your code here
                settingsViewModel.languageSetting.setValue(binding.languageSetting.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });

        binding.currencySetting.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // your code here
                settingsViewModel.currencySetting.setValue(binding.currencySetting.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });

        return binding.getRoot();


    }
```

The view model :

```
public void onSaveClick() {
        String masterKeyAlias = null;

        try {
            masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);
            sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                    "shared_prefs",
                    masterKeyAlias,
                    context,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
            );
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // use the shared preferences and editor as you normally would
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("languageSetting", languageSetting.getValue());
        editor.putString("currencySetting", currencySetting.getValue());
        editor.putBoolean("notiSetting", notiSetting.getValue());
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();

        Log.d("mutlangxxc", sharedPreferences.getString("languageSetting",""));
        Log.d("mutlangwww", sharedPreferences.getString("currencySetting",""));


    }
```

Then activity :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("shared_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.d("languageSetting", mSharedPrefs.getString("langaugeSetting", "" +"kkk"));
        Log.d("currencySetting", mSharedPrefs.getString("currencySetting", ""));
        Log.d("notiSetting", String.valueOf(mSharedPrefs.getBoolean("notiSetting", false)));

        if (mSharedPrefs.contains("langaugeSetting")) {
            Log.d("hasSetting", "true");
        } else {
            Log.d("hasSetting", "fase");
        }
```

When i print them just after set them in view model it printed nice but when i print them in activity it can't be printed .. also when i check if it contains some key, it gives me false

How to fix it?